# Date periods based on first occurence

Tags: list, pandas, period

I have a pandas data frame of orders:

```
OrderID OrderDate   Value   CustomerID
1       2017-11-01  12.56   23
2       2017-11-06  1.56    23
3       2017-11-08  2.67    23
4       2017-11-12  5.67    99
5       2017-11-13  7.88    23
6       2017-11-19  3.78    99
```

Let's look at customer with ID 23.
His first order in the history was 2017-11-01. This date is a start date for his first week. It means that all his orders between 2017-11-01 and 2017-11-07 are assigned to his week number 1 (It IS NOT a calendar week like Monday to Sunday).
For customer with ID 99 first week starts 2017-11-12 of course as it is a date of his first order (OrderId 6).

I need to assign every order of the table to the respective index of the common table Periods. Periods[0] will contain orders from customer's weeks number 1, Periods[1] from customer's weeks number 2 etc.
OrderId 1 nad OrderId 6 will be in the same index of Periods table as both orders were created in first week of their customers.

Period table containig orders IDs has to look like this:
Periods=[[1,2,4],[3,5,6]]

Comment: What is your expected out from this data?

Comment: I need to create a cohort. Usually cohorts are based on calendar weeks or months. Using calendar weeks results for first week will be obscured if a customer make his first order on Sunday, in this case we will count orders from this day only. I want to avoid this.

Comment: Can you produce the actual table you are expecting with the given dataframe,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
df['New']=df.groupby('CustomerID').OrderDate.apply(lambda x : (x-x.iloc[0]).dt.days//7)
df.groupby('New').OrderID.apply(list)
Out[1079]: 
New
0    [1, 2, 4]
1    [3, 5, 6]
Name: OrderID, dtype: object
```

To get your period table

```
df.groupby('New').OrderID.apply(list).tolist()
Out[1080]: [[1, 2, 4], [3, 5, 6]]
```

---

More info

```
df
Out[1081]: 
   OrderID  OrderDate  Value  CustomerID  New
0        1 2017-11-01  12.56          23    0
1        2 2017-11-06   1.56          23    0
2        3 2017-11-08   2.67          23    1
3        4 2017-11-12   5.67          99    0
4        5 2017-11-13   7.88          23    1
5        6 2017-11-19   3.78          99    1
```

Comment: Exactly! You are awesome. Thx!

Comment: @czyzyk14 if it is want you need . Can you consider accept it?

Comment: Accepted, sorry I am new here.

Comment: @czyzyk14 aha, happy coding